# How to Add Product to Wishlist Programmatically Using Object Manager in Magento2

Tags: magento2, collection, wishlist, object-manager

I have existing product slider and that slider made with object manager so I want to add the product to wishlist by Product id Using Object Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution.

```
<a href="#" data-post='<?php  echo $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getAddParams($product) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span>Add to wishlist</span></a>
```